# Get specific value from json response not working

Tags: php, arrays

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QEO5O.png)

I have the following json response as in the image. I would want to access specific value, like: "ROUMANIE ROVA AROMANIA" but I can't seem to get to it. I tried the following:

```
$response =  json_decode($r->getBody(),true);

foreach($response['ParsedResults'] as $key)
{

             foreach($key['TextOverlay']['Lines'] as $bla)

             {

                 echo $bla['LineText'];
                 echo $bla[0]['LineText'];
             }

}
```

If I only echo one depth, it's working. I searched for a solution but none did the trick. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`0` is the current index of the first item, `$bla` contains already the data you're looking for, so doing this directly should work:

`echo $bla['LineText'];`

Here is how the full code should look like:

```
$response = [
    'ParsedResults' => [
        [
            'TextOverlay' => [
                    'Lines' => [
                            [
                                'LineText' => 'ROUMANIE ROVA AROMANIA',
                                'Words' => [
                                        [
                                            'WordText' => 'ROUMANIE',
                                            'OtherData' => 'whatever'
                                        ],
                                        [
                                            'WordText' => 'ROVA',
                                            'OtherData' => 'whatever'
                                        ],
                                        [
                                            'WordText' => 'AROMANIA',
                                            'OtherData' => 'whatever'
                                        ],
                                    ]
                            ]
                        ]
                ]
        ]
    ]
];

foreach($response['ParsedResults'] as $key)
{
     foreach($key['TextOverlay']['Lines'] as $bla)
     {
         echo $bla['LineText'];
     }
}
```

Tested here: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/0577e854eed73dfb33193c391acc37dd81baf982

Comment: Not sure what you're doing wrong, please see the example I attached above.